# LM311 overheating

Tags: analog, comparator, overheat

I breadboarded the circuited below. Within seconds of operation, both the L7805 and LM311 start to overheat very badly.

I tought it had something to do with the coupling capacitor or the AC signal so I removed the signal source and capacitor, then simply shunted the CMP+ input to ground using the 1k resistor - still got overheating. When I leave the CMP+ input open there's no overheating. Any ideas why this is happening is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Why do you use 12V on the inverting input bias? Why not derive that from the 5V that you are using for Vcc? If that diode (U5) doesn't conduct, you'll put 12 V on the inverting input and this is going to be problematic. This device does not tolerate inputs going beyond the rails. You need to have some dc bias on the non-inverting input.

Comment: The pinout and schematic looks ok so you have probably miswired it so it doesn't;t match the schematic. Make sure you are counting the pins on the LM311 the correct way. Maybe a picture of your layout would help us.

Comment: It also could be that your comparator is oscillating at high frequency and drawing excess current.  I don’t see decoupling caps on the comparator supply pins and you don’t show the layout so it’s hard to tell.  You should add decoupling, and a DC path for the non-inverting input’s bias current.  You can check the output with a scope to see if it’s oscillating.

Comment: Pin 2 of the LM311 needs a DC current path for biasing; maybe 1k ohms to the U5 cathode.   This does NOT explain overheating, though.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I've heard that the LM311 does not sense below 0.5V if the Vee is ground. The AC signal does drop to ground sometimes, could this cause some issue? If so, this could explain the overheating when I simply connected CMP+ to ground with the 1k resistor.

Comment: @strange_bakery That is true. You need to prevent the input from going to the rails. Best  operation is 1/2Vcc+/-1/4Vcc.